# How to extend Hapi types [Typescript]

Tags: typescript, hapi.js

I am trying to add new type to existsing hapi definitions...
I want to add seneca type... Here is example

```
interface SenecaMethods {
    act: any;
    add: any;
}

interface HapiServer extends Hapi.Server {
    info: any;
    seneca: SenecaMethods;
}

const server: HapiServer = new Hapi.Server();
```

> Error it return Server is not assignable to HapiServer, property
>   'seneca' missing in type server.

How is possbile to add it seneca methods to Hapi.Server? I can put seneca as optional but I don't want it to be optional....

Comment: Take a look into the Declaration section (TypeScript doc) : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Comment: What part, could you show example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

**cast:**

```
const server: HapiServer = new Hapi.Server() as HapiServer;

//server.seneca === undefined
```

**union**

```
const server: HapiServer = Object.assign(new Hapi.Server(),
    { seneca: { act: "foo", add: "bar" } }
  )
```

**extend**

```
class MyHapiServer extends Hapi.Server {
  info: any;
  seneca: SenecaMethods;

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.seneca = {
      act:"foo", 
      add:"bar",
    }
  }
}

const server: MyHapiServer = new MyHapiServer();
```